# UIRefreshControl lag

Tags: iphone, objective-c, rss, uirefreshcontrol

I've developed an RSS Feed with an UIRefreshControl in order to refresh the contents. But whenever I trigger the UIRefreshControl, it lags terribly. There is no lag if I'm on Wifi but a lot of lag if I'm on a slow data connection.

Has anybody an idea why this is happening?

Comment: Never do synchronous networking in the middle of your UI code.

Comment: @H2CO3 how can I do it differently? My refreshControl is just calling the action to refresh the tableview

Comment: Put all networking in the background. Load the data asynchronously, refresh the table view when it's loaded.

Comment: please post code related to refreshing or data fetching

Comment: @MidhunMP I posted the code, thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are downloading and parsing the data in main thread. That's why it is hanging. Never do time consuming tasks on main thread, it'll block your UI.

Change your:

```
-(void) refreshInvoked:(id)sender forState:(UIControlState)state
{
    [self reloadFeed];
}
```

like:

```
-(void) refreshInvoked:(id)sender forState:(UIControlState)state
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_queue_create("midhun", NULL), ^{
         [self reloadFeed];
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I never worked with other threads before, that's incredibly nice :D